# How to make a Double Clickable File that runs commands in Terminal?

Tags: terminal

I want to make a file that when double clicked runs those two commands in Terminal:

```
cd /Users/sheriferrefae/Documents/Native\ Instruments/Traktor\ 3.9.0 
Java -jar LibraryParser.jar
```

Please help